# Showing a Windows form in wpf

Tags: wpf, winforms, touch

I'm working on some multi-touch Surface computers for my workplace (mainly for meetings and presentation), and not being wholly familiar with WPF, I was wondering if I might be able to put some Windows Forms in a Surface project so that several users could ostensibly use programs at the same time.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make winform run on WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387921/how-to-make-winform-run-on-wpf) Has been asked numerous times - use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the reason why you want to include windows forms into a WPF project, but if that's all you want to do, check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). WindowsFormsHost Class is used to manage WinForms things in WPF.

Please mark my reply as answer if it solves your problem.

Thanks,